# 401: Access denied. You are not authorized to read activity records

Tags: google-admin-sdk, http-status-code-401

I am trying to test `https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/reports/v1/activity/users/{userKey or all}/applications/{applicationName}` in the browser using the API explorer utility but I am getting below error.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Access denied. You are not authorized to read activity records.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Access denied. You are not authorized to read activity records.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "authError",
        "location": "Authorization",
        "locationType": "header"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I have enabled all the necessary API scopes for the OAuth client. below is the screenshot of the scopes that I have enabled for my client.

[image]

Comment: Are you authenticating as the domain admin with the necessary privelleges when performing this request?

Comment: @ziganotschka You were right. I was trying with a user who didn't have permissions to access these APIs. I changed the subject user and it started working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

The user which I was using along with the service account didn't have proper permission to access some of these APIs. I switched to a subject user with all necessary permissions and it started working fine for me.